# How Massive database queries works

Tags: database, database-design

For a few days now I've been thinking on how Google and other massive companies like Facebook build their database structure and how their submit queries, today I have been all over the web trying to find answer for **specific** question I'm interesting in but i couldn't find any relevance information.

My questions:

1. Sites like Facebook receive millions of updates every hour, probably the rows get massive amounts of data in no time, **how** does Facebook able to manage all this data, and find for a specific user and specific row in a millions of rows and probably millions of tables, even though it probably based on time tables it's insane?
2. In massive website like Facebook and Google+ you can find in the URL bar a massive number such as `100001111421958` ,`116447414911527915678` and this found in the account URL and it doesn't make sense, **and to my question**: is there a special database structure that use this technique with the big number (rows?) thing?

Is there any article on massive database structure and how to submit query with millions of rows works, if there is a technique and so on.

Comment: why is there `jquery` and `javascript` tag in the question

Comment: I'd guess the reason behind Google's speed is a trade secret...

Comment: @3nigma probably a mistake since it close to query*..

Answer (score 0):

This is the beauty of a distributed system that you feel like you are interacting with a single system.

As far as performance is concerned the minimum response time can be achieved by various theoretical bookish techniques like redundancy and caching and then there are techniques to overcome the inherent problems of concurrency and consistency. Books and books are written on these issues but understanding the system architecture of Google and Facebook is not that simple they have incorporated many unconventional techniques and developed many by themselves.